# Ocultar div de acuerdo a la opción seleccionada mediante select

Tags: javascript, formularios, entrada

Quisiera saber quien me puede ayudar con el siguiente código, tengo un formulario en el cual quisiera lograr que al escoger la opción de soy asociado el `input` cédula quede activado y de lo contrario si la opción seleccionada es no soy asociado se desactive y deje ingresar los demás campos

Código HTML

```js
 $('#select').on('change',function(){
        var selectValor = $(this).val();
        alert (selectValor);

        if (selectValor == 'opc1') {
            $('.cedula')addClass('.oculto');
        }else {
            alert('esta es la opcion 2')
        }
    });
```

```css
.oculto{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="container container-form pb-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class=" formulario col-12">
        <form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" >
          <div class="row" >

            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" name="select" id="select">
                  <option value="">¿Es Asosiado?</option>
                  <option value="opc1">Soy Asosiado</option>
                  <option value="opc2">No soy Asosiado</option>
                </select>
               </div>
             </div> 
              
             <div class="col-md-6 cedula">
                  <div class="form-group mb-5">
                      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Cedula">
                      
                  </div>
              </div>

             <div class="col-md-6 nombre " >
                  <div class="form-group mb-5">
                      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre Completo">
                      
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group mb-5">
                      <input type="tel" id="phone" name="telefono" class="form-control" placeholder="Télefono/Celular">
                     
                  </div>
              </div>
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group mb-5">
                      <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo">
                     
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group mb-5">
                      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Departamento">
                     
                  </div>
              </div>
             
          </div>
            </form>

            
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes errores puntuales, como por ejemplo hace falta el punto de separación para utilizar el método `addClass` y añadir una clase, además este método acepta el nombre de la clase tal cuál sin el punto adiciona, como se hace referencia en `CSS` para las clases.

```
.addClass('oculto');
```

La validación está mal, la `opc1` pertenece a "soy asociado" por lo cuál ahí deberías remover la clase y no añadirla, y en el `else` hacer lo contrario.

Ejm

```js
$('#select').on('change',function(){
 var selectValor = $(this).val();
 if (selectValor == 'opc1') {
   $('.cedula').removeClass('oculto');
 }else {
  $('.cedula').addClass('oculto');
 }
});
```

```css
.oculto{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
    <div class="container container-form pb-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class=" formulario col-12">
        <form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" >
          <div class="row" >

            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" name="select" id="select">
                  <option value="">¿Es Asociado?</option>
                  <option value="opc1">Soy Asociado</option>
                  <option value="opc2">No soy Asociado</option>
                </select>
               </div>
             </div> 
              
             <div class="col-md-6 cedula">
                  <div class="form-group mb-5">
                      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Cedula">
                      
                  </div>
              </div>

             <div class="col-md-6 nombre " >
                  <div class="form-group mb-5">
                      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre Completo">
                      
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group mb-5">
                      <input type="tel" id="phone" name="telefono" class="form-control" placeholder="Télefono/Celular">
                     
                  </div>
              </div>
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group mb-5">
                      <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo">
                     
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group mb-5">
                      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Departamento">
                     
                  </div>
              </div>
             
          </div>
            </form>

            
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Además este funcionamiento se puede lograr utilizando el método [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) pasando como segundo parámetro la validación  `selectValor != 'opc1'`

```js
 $('#select').on('change',function(){
  var selectValor = $(this).val();
  if(selectValor){
    $('.cedula').toggleClass('oculto',(selectValor != 'opc1'));
  }else{
    alert("seleccione una opción ");
  }
});
```

```css
.oculto{
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section>
 <div class="container container-form pb-5">
 <div class="row">
  <div class=" formulario col-12">
   <form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" >
    <div class="row" >

     <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group">
       <select class="form-control" name="select" id="select">
        <option value="">¿Es Asociado?</option>
        <option value="opc1">Soy Asociado</option>
        <option value="opc2">No soy Asociado</option>
       </select>
       </div>
      </div> 
      
      <div class="col-md-6 cedula">
        <div class="form-group mb-5">
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Cedula">
          
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 nombre " >
        <div class="form-group mb-5">
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre Completo">
          
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group mb-5">
          <input type="tel" id="phone" name="telefono" class="form-control" placeholder="Télefono/Celular">
          
        </div>
      </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group mb-5">
          <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo">
          
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group mb-5">
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Departamento">
          
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
     </form>

     
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Sin utilizar clases, también se puede utilizar el método [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) para mostrar y ocultar elementos pasando como parámetro la validación `selectValor == 'opc1'`

```js
 $('#select').on('change',function(){
  var selectValor = $(this).val();
  if(selectValor){
    $('.cedula').toggle(selectValor == 'opc1');
  }else{
    alert("seleccione una opción ");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
 <div class="container container-form pb-5">
 <div class="row">
  <div class=" formulario col-12">
   <form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" >
    <div class="row" >

     <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group">
       <select class="form-control" name="select" id="select">
        <option value="">¿Es Asociado?</option>
        <option value="opc1">Soy Asociado</option>
        <option value="opc2">No soy Asociado</option>
       </select>
       </div>
      </div> 
      
      <div class="col-md-6 cedula">
        <div class="form-group mb-5">
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Cedula">
          
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 nombre " >
        <div class="form-group mb-5">
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre Completo">
          
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group mb-5">
          <input type="tel" id="phone" name="telefono" class="form-control" placeholder="Télefono/Celular">
          
        </div>
      </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group mb-5">
          <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo">
          
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group mb-5">
          <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Departamento">
          
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
     </form>

     
  </div>
 </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: No sería más eficiente utilizar el hide/show? ya que el OP sólo está tratando de esconder un elemento; se justificaría si además de esconderlo quisiera agregarle nuevas características al input no?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera Sí, eso añadió en su respuesta, no iba a duplicarla, solo quería mostrar donde falla y como podría hacerse de las dos formas posibles. Utilizando clases y cuando no se desea hacerlo.

Comment: @Jessicaquintero qué bueno que mi respuesta pueda ayudarle, recuerde si  la respuesta te sirvió y/o  solucionó el problema, puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: @Dev.Joel Aclarado colega :) Muy buena respuesta

Answer (score 5):

Tienes varios errores en tu código

- el `addClass` debería anteponerse por un punto (.) de lo contrario te dará error.
- no necesitas crear una clase oculto cuando `JQuery` tiene las funciones necesarias para esconder o mostrar elementos.

Te adjunto el código

```js
$('#select').on('change',function(){
        var selectValor = $(this).val();
        //alert (selectValor);

        if (selectValor == 'opc1') {
            $('.cedula').show();
        }else {
          $('.cedula').hide();
            //alert('esta es la opcion 2')
        }
    });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container mt-3">
  <section>
    <div class="container container-form pb-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class=" formulario col-12">
        <form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" >
          <div class="row" >

            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control" name="select" id="select">
                  <option value="">¿Es Asosiado?</option>
                  <option value="opc1">Soy Asosiado</option>
                  <option value="opc2">No soy Asosiado</option>
                </select>
               </div>
             </div> 
              
             <div class="col-md-6 cedula">
                  <div class="form-group mb-5">
                      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Cedula">
                      
                  </div>
              </div>

             <div class="col-md-6 nombre " >
                  <div class="form-group mb-5">
                      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre Completo">
                      
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group mb-5">
                      <input type="tel" id="phone" name="telefono" class="form-control" placeholder="Télefono/Celular">
                     
                  </div>
              </div>
               <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group mb-5">
                      <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo">
                     
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                  <div class="form-group mb-5">
                      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Departamento">
                     
                  </div>
              </div>
             
          </div>
            </form>

            
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Nos comentas si es lo que buscas colega :)